# How to propagate a table column with the same value 600 times

Tags: sql

How can I propagate a table column with the same value 600 times with a link in every row without writing over some values that might already be there.

I can't get this to work:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET column_name = REPLACE ( column_name,'NULL','new values' )
```

I know I must be close? Thanks everyone.

Comment: You want to update 600 rows or you want `'new values'` concatenated together 600 times in the same column or you want to update all rows 600 times?

Comment: You mean like 1 to many? I forget which is which. Sorry: Mine goes DB->5tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
UPDATE TABLE SET column_name = 'new values' WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`UPDATE TABLE SET column_name = column_name+'new values'`

If the `+` doesn't work, use whatever concatenate function applies to your RDBMS

Comment: UPDATE hotels SET url = 'new values'
Worked but replaced my previous entries. Oh well. Thanks though.

Comment: you had to set url = url+'new values' like i posted !

Comment: You needed the `WHERE url IS NULL` clause.